error during build [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/src/main.jsx" from "/opt/build/repo/index.html"
I can't deploy my project on netlify and I faced a Rollup failed error while deploying and i uploaded my project via GitHub.
How to solve this error and deploy my project?
The error I face:
Error during build:
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/src/main.jsx" from "/opt/build/repo/index.html".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`

